# React Native function for getting an Oauth 2.0 token

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm porting an app from React to React Native but this function for getting a token from an api returns 'undefined' as a response when being called with a useEffect hook. After looking into the issue more it seems like the URLSearchParams function might not work with React Native.

```
  const getToken = async (req, res) => {


    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    params.append("client_id", key);
    params.append("client_secret", secret);
    const petfinderRes = await fetch(
      "https://api.petfinder.com/v2/oauth2/token",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: params,
      }
    );
    const data = await petfinderRes.json();
    console.log('data', data.access_token)
    setToken(data.access_token);
  };
```

I get the following errors from the api:

```
"errors": Array [
    Object {
      "code": "unsupported_grant_type",
      "details": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server. - Check that all required parameters have been provided",
      "href": "http://developer.petfinder.com/v2/errors.html#unsupported_grant_type",
      "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server. - Check that all required parameters have been provided",
      "title": "Unauthorized",
    },
  ],
  "hint": "Check that all required parameters have been provided",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "type": "https://httpstatus.es/400",
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, by "does not get the token"? Do you get a compilation error, a runtime error? Maybe an empty response from the server, etc. How are you calling this function in React Native? We need a bit more details here to be able to help.

Comment: My apologies, I've added more information about the issue hopefully that is more clear. Thank you!